# Channels2 isn't working on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-channels

It works on my localhost. But when I deploy on AWS ElasticBeanstalk, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 523, in resolve
raise Resolver404({'tried': tried, 'path': new_path})

django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404: {'tried': [[<URLPattern '^$' [name='home']>], [<URLPattern '^comunidade/'>]], 'path': 'socket/comunidade/'}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 99, in get_exception_response
response = callback(request, **dict(param_dict, exception=exception))

TypeError: handler404() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exception'
```

My routing.py:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({

    "websocket": OriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter([
                # URLRouter just takes standard Django path() or url() entries.
                path("socket/", MyConsumer),
                url("socket/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)", MyConsumer),
            ]),
        ),
        [".mydomain.com.br", "localhost"]
    ),
})
```

My JS connection:

```
var ws_scheme = window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
var connection = new WebSocket( ws_scheme + "://" + window.location.host + "/socket" + window.location.pathname );
```

In AWS config, WSGIPath is pointing to `wsgi.py`. It seems to be routing channels 2 to `urls.py`

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using AWS?

Comment: is there any reason not to use it? :)

Comment: I launched on Digital Ocean, it was super easy.

Comment: before deploy try to create your requirements.txt files... When deploy try to install all your dependency and run your app again

Comment: I have a requirements file...and everything works fine on localhost with same requirements